# Wrapping case statements within a window function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below sql and would like to add a filter clause within the window function. Is this possible?

```
select ROUND(SUM(M.CHRG_RATE/M.CONTRACTUAL_RATE) OVER 
           (PARTITION BY M.PROGRAM),0) AS BILLED_MEMBERS_PER_MONTH2
from tableA
where 1=1
```

I was thinking I could wrap a case statement?

Something like:

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` to leave rows out of the `sum`.  For example, this only sums rows where the `flag` column equals `'Q'`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN M.FLAG = 'Q' THEN M.CHRG_RATE/M.CONTRACTUAL_RATE END)
```